# find a cell with specific text, multiple occurences, and past active cell in all cells containing specific text

Tags: vba, excel, find

I am currently working on a report, originating in Infoview (SAP business Objects)

This is a report that provides valuable information on a weekly basis, to enhance awareness of current shop performance.

Like the tile of the post might show i want to find a cell with specific text. It has multiple occurrences, and I want to past a previously selected cell in all of those instances.

I can reach the same result by Ctrl-F, "Search all" ( for the "specific text") and than Paste (the previously selected cell)
 ( http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/816-excel-select-cells-with-specific-text.html) 
But i would like to automate this.

I want to use:

```
    Cells.Find(What:="[ö]", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

and

```
      Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
```

But I can't incorporate the two in one macro that gives me the result i describes above.

The previously selected cell contains a formula, containing index(match) and a reference to a cell on the same row as the "specific text". 
 In my opinion this way of doing stuff saves me a lot of trouble with dynamic cell references ect.

I hope you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is a little vague, but I believe this will get you started

```
Dim PasteValue as string 'this is what you're pasting in
Dim WS as Worksheet
Dim FirstCell as string
Dim rng as range

PasteValue = 'do something here to get your value

set rng = Cells.Find(What:="[ö]", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False)
while not rng is nothing    'make sure you found something
  if len(FirstCell) = 0 then
     firstcell = rng.address    'save this spot off so we don't keep looping
  end if
  rng.value = PasteValue
  'now find the next one
  set rng = Cells.Find(What:="[ö]", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= xlPart, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
      SearchFormat:=False)
  if rng.address = FirstCell then  'back at the first cell
    set rng = nothing              'so get out of the loop
  endif
end while
```

Comment: It it almost right i believe ! Thanks. However, I paste a formula in cell S11--> ( Range("S11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-9]=1,"""",INDEX('Source samenwerken'!R1C13:R60000C13,MATCH(RC[-16],'Source samenwerken'!R1C4:R60000C4,0)+COUNTIF('Source samenwerken'!R1C4:R60000C4,RC[-16])-1))"
  ). I want that formula in every cell that contains [ö], corresponding with the row number the [ö] is in. for that I can easilly copy and paste cell S11, But How can I use the Cell S11 as "PasteValue" ?

Comment: `set rng = cells.find()` will find a cell with "[ö]". `rng.value = PasteValue` will put "PasteValue" in that cell. Since you're pasting in a formula, you need to change that to `rng.formula = PasteValue`. You need to set "PasteValue" to whatever it is that you need to have pasted in.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code above, it helped a lot.

This is the final code, in case anyone needs it. The

```
If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Do
Loop While rng.Address <> strFirstAddress
```

is particulary usefull.

```
Sub Fill_VCNC()
Dim formula_ö As String 
Dim rng As Range
Dim strFirstAddress As String  

With Range("S:S")
     Set rng = Cells.Find(What:="[ö]", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
SearchFormat:=False)
     If Not rng Is Nothing Then
         strFirstAddress = rng.Address
         Do
            rng.formula = formula_ö
            .NumberFormat = "0.00"
            Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
            If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Do
         Loop While rng.Address <> strFirstAddress
    End If
 End With
End Sub
```

( source : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/958fca4e-b19d-4b50-8235-e05adc7f25d5/loop-through-a-range-until-value-not-found?forum=exceldev)